# Compiz Grid/Put Not Working After Upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: compiz, window-manager

On Ubuntu 17.04, I had CompizConfig set up so that `Ctrl+Alt+Key pad number` would place the current window into the appropriate quarter/half of the screen.

This is not working after upgrading to 17.10.  I've tried changing the Grid and Put settings in Compiz but nothing seems to take effect.

In addition, I have an external monitor connected to my laptop and now `Ctrl+Alt+4` and `Ctrl+Alt+6` move the window from one monitor to the next.  I want the window to remain on the current monitor.

How can I get this back?

Update: I'm using GNOME display environment. I had Wayland setup by default after the upgrade but disabled it due to another issue I was experiencing.

Comment: GNOME does not use Compiz under Xorg nor Wayland. If you want to continue using Compiz, you'll need to switch to a different environment that uses it. I wouldn't recommend Unity, as it is no longer supported, and expected to be removed from 18.04 though. I'm not sure what other environments rely on Compiz today.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to Unity and everything went back to normal.

`sudo apt install unity`

Then restart and at the login screen, click the settings gear icon and select "Unity".

My system was running terribly slow with GNOME and now it's speedy again as well.